centos7 cron job pam_limit invalid line hard nproc skipped
I am getting the error:
May 29 19:15:02 vps3.domain.com crond[19846]: pam_limits(crond:session): invalid line 'user3 hard nproc ' - skipped
May 29 19:15:02 vps3.domain.com crond[19846]: pam_limits(crond:sess:on): invalid line 'user4 hard nproc ' - skipped

The cron line is:
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user3/public_html/api/crons/cron-mailer.php

I have tried many solutions from stacks and nothing works.
I've tried:

Adding on /etc/security/limits.conf
root            soft    nproc          200000
root            hard    nproc          200000

sysctl1 -w fs.file-max=200000


The restarting the cron but I still get the above errors on systemctl status crond
What's the solution to this problem as I cannot run any crons at all?
Update:
Contents of /etc/security/limits.conf
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#This file sets the resource limits for the users logged in via PAM.
#It does not affect resource limits of the system services.
#
#Also note that configuration files in /etc/security/limits.d directory,
#which are read in alphabetical order, override the settings in this
#file in case the domain is the same or more specific.
#That means for example that setting a limit for wildcard domain here
#can be overriden with a wildcard setting in a config file in the
#subdirectory, but a user specific setting here can be overriden only
#with a user specific setting in the subdirectory.
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - a user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open file descriptors
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit (KB)
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

# End of file


*               soft    nofile         200000
*               hard    nofile         200000
*               soft    nproc          200000
*               hard    nproc          200000
root            soft    nofile         200000
root            hard    nofile         200000
root            soft    nproc          200000
root            hard    nproc          200000

Update 2:
Files in /etc/security/limit.d/
20-nproc.conf
Contents:
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

*          soft    nproc     4096
root       soft    nproc     unlimited

Then there's a file for every user with the contents:
user1 hard nproc 
user1 hard nofile 


Can you post the entire contents of your /etc/security/limits.conf?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica added to post. Many thanks

That still doesn't account for the error you got. Are there any files in /etc/security/limits.d/? If so, can you post them too?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Updated

This is the problem:

Then there's a file for every user with the contents:
user1 hard nproc 
user1 hard nofile


Those entries are invalid because they don't have values. Either add values to the end of them all, or remove them entirely.

Deleting all the user files with the other changes I made might have fixed it. I'll update the OP if it doesn't work.
